# How to integrate video js with next js?

Tags: next.js, video.js

Currently, I am integrating video js just like video js docs but it's not working please help me, anyone.! It's not working

```
 <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>
```

Comment: As an answer that was deleted for some reason said, there's an example in the next.js docs https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-videojs

Answer (score -2):

You may want to use next-videos library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-videos

or simply put your video file into public folder and add this line to your code :

```
<video controls src={"/filename.mp4"} style={{ width: "400px", height"400px" }} />
```

Comment: I cant use videojs with next ?